# How to insert a dropped join key column from Dataframe join in order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

**Inputs**

I have these two dataframes

```
current_rComp = 
   #1  X  Y
0  p1  A  B

next_rComp = 
   #2  X  Z
0  p2  A  C
1  p3  A  D
```

I need to inner join 2 dataframes with the same key (`X`) and restore the dropped `X` column of `next_rComp`. So I tried as below.

```
key = current_rComp.columns.intersection(next_rComp.columns).tolist()
proof_path = pd.merge(current_rComp, next_rComp,how='inner', on=key)
key_column = proof_path[key].add_suffix('_')
proof_path = pd.concat([proof_path, key_column], axis=1)
```

**output**

```
proof_path =
   #1  X  Y  #2  Z X_
0  p1  A  B  p2  C  A
1  p1  A  B  p3  D  A
```

I want to restore the dropped X column of next_rComp to the column order of next_rComp before join.

My desired output is

```
proof_path =
   #1  X  Y  #2 X_  Z
0  p1  A  B  p2  A  C
1  p1  A  B  p3  A  D
```

Is there an easy way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use `left_on` and `right_on` parameters in `merge` with rename  columns `key` by prefix and also columns of second DataFrame by dictionary:

```
#removed converting to list and if necessary sort=False
key = current_rComp.columns.intersection(next_rComp.columns, sort=False)

new_key = key + '_'
d = dict(zip(key, new_key))
print (d)
{'X': 'X_'}

proof_path = pd.merge(current_rComp, 
                      next_rComp.rename(columns=d),
                      how='inner', 
                      left_on=key.tolist(), 
                      right_on=new_key.tolist())

print (proof_path)
   #1  X  Y  #2 X_  Z
0  p1  A  B  p2  A  C
1  p1  A  B  p3  A  D
```